# Problems with mathtools package

Tags: table-of-contents, etoolbox, mathtools

The following code produces an error. If the mathtools package is removed, it works. Why?

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{shorttoc}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@startshorttoc}{\bgroup}{\bgroup\booltrue{shorttoc}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\ifbool{shorttoc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}{}}

\chapter{Test Appendix}

\end{document}
```

---

This question is related to [an earlier question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64999/remove-entries-from-short-toc-but-not-from-long-toc).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`mathtools` loads the `calc` package, which change the `\setcounter` command. You now have to protect it too:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\ifbool{shorttoc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}{}}
```

Comment: For reference I add the following link: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=protect