# How to Remove Certain Chapters from \shorttableofcontents but Keep it in \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, shorttoc

I am writing my thesis in the French language - see below for a minimal working example - I need to have a summary which is practically a succinct table of contents containing only parts, chapters, and sections; I also need to provide an exhaustive table of contents at the end of the thesis which includes subsections.

I am using `\shorttableofcontents` because if I use `\tableofcontents` twice, one of them is rendered **blank**.

I would like that the \chapter{Appendices} *to be only included in the second `toc`* but no mention of it in the `\shorttableofcontents`, no matter what I tried, it doesn't seem to work, and I couldn't find questions with similar cases.

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setcode{utf8}

\begin{document}
\shorttableofcontents{Summary}{1}
\frontmatter
\chapter{General Introduction}

\mainmatter
\chapter{CH1}
\chapter{CH2}
\chapter{CH3}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendices}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was taken from

[Remove entries from short ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65003/161015)

**Short TOC** (parts, chapter and sections, but not appendices)

[image: ss]

**Complete ToC**

[image: ll]

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{shorttoc}   
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%   \usepackage{arabtex}
%   \usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% ****************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65003/161015
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtoggle{onlyshorttoc}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@startshorttoc}{\bgroup}{\bgroup\toggletrue{onlyshorttoc}}{}{}
\makeatother
% ******************************

\begin{document}
    \shorttableofcontents{Summary}{1}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{General Introduction}
    
    \mainmatter
    \part{PI}
    \chapter{CH1}
    \section{SCH1}
    \subsection{SSCH1}
    \chapter{CH2}
        \section{SCH2}
    \subsection{SSCH2}
        \part{PII}  
    \chapter{CH3}
    \section{SCH3}
    \subsection{SSCH3}
    
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\iftoggle{onlyshorttoc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}{}} % added <<<<<<<<<<
    \backmatter
    \chapter{App First}
    \chapter{App Second}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % added <<<<<<<<<<
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{document}
```

First adds a boolean, set as true, to the `shottoc` code.

Then, before the appendices, adds in the `.toc` file a command to set the depth of the toc = -1 (don't show chapters and lower levels) if the boolean is true.